# Finding Linux driver for Linksys AE1200 USB WiFi dongle

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers

Recently purchased a Linksys AE1200 USB WiFi dongle to use with my Debian box for setting up a WiFi AP.

Unfortunately it doesnt seem to work out of the box and I cant seem to find any Linux drivers online. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get it working.

Comment: it's apparently a BCM43235, which should work with the `brcmfmac` driver. However, that driver is somewhat new, you may need a more recent kernel that Debian provides, especially if you are using Debian Stable.

Comment: @BatchyX: You should make that comment an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is 10 years old, but there are still issues when trying to use this dongle.

The device is a Linksys AE1200, and USB databases list it as `13b1:0039` – as you can [see here](https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/13b1/0039).

The problem is that, when you reboot the PC, `13b1:0039` gets recognized as `13b1:0bdc`, which prevents it from loading the `brcmfmac` kernel module.  Because `0bdc` is not a real product.

A tedious workaround was to physically unplug and replug it, since it gets identified as `0039` the second time (you can confirm this by running `lsusb` before and after replugging).

After lots of troubleshooting, I found an automated way of doing this, without touching anything. The answer is based off of [shodanex's reply to a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/442867/117259).

It involves explicitly telling the drivers to also be used with the device's incorrect ID.

---

### Steps to fix

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, or open your favorite terminal.

All the following commands must be run as `sudo`, but I got "permission denied" when running it as-is. So, run `sudo -i` before anything. (if you get a prompt that says `#` instead of the regular `$`, you're all set)

Because `brcmfmac` might not even be loaded, you may need to load it yourself. So type:

```
modprobe brcmfmac
```

Now for the actual fix, let's tell `brcmfmac` to also use this wrong ID:

```
echo 13b1 0bdc > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/brcmfmac/new_id
```

This will make sure the device uses the `brcmfmac` module, even if its ID is incorrect.  After a few seconds, the dongle should be recognized, allowing you to configure a WiFi network!

You can do that through the GUI as usual or run `nmtui` on another terminal if you have it installed.

If everything went well, you should have a working internet connection.

---

Now that we know it works, we can automate this by running a cronjob every time the system boots.

Run:

```
crontab -e
```

As a superuser (which you should be, if you followed the steps), and you'll be shown an editor with an empty file. Paste the commands that fixed the issue in there (on different lines) and add `@reboot` at the start of both, like so:

```
@reboot modprobe brcmfmac
@reboot echo 13b1 0bdc > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/brcmfmac/new_id
```

This tells the system to run those commands (as `sudo`) every time you boot it. In case your distro doesn't support it, you can search for other methods.

#### More info

I tried a lot of things before coming up with this, and was about to give up on the issue. Luckily, someone else seems to have [reported it as an official bug at Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1001189).

Of course, it's not a bug from Debian, as other distros have the same issue. It should be the kernel, but don't know if it's been reported upstream yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have had luck in Ubuntu using "Windows Wireless Drivers" and the dongle's windows driver.

[See Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/internet/C/ndiswrapper.html)

Since Ubuntu is Debian based there is probably a Debian equivalent.

Comment: Oh really? which driver did you use because when I tried none of them would install apart from the vista one, and that couldnt start the device as it gave some driver error.

Comment: My dongle is a different brand.  I used the XP drivers if I am remembering correctly.  It worked in Ubuntu at home and Mint at work.  My dongle is a "CNet Wireless-N PicoUSB Dongle CQU-906"

Answer (score 0):

The solution using crontab almost works on my Debian/Trixie system. The commands execute but I get an error message sent to me that says:

```
"/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /sys/bus/usb/drivers/brcmfmac/new_id: Directory nonexistent"
```

However when I run the echo command as root, it works.

The solution is to join the two commands into a single line so they execute sequentially:

@reboot /usr/sbin/modprobe brcmfmac && echo 13b1 0bdc > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/brcmfmac/new_id

This forces the echo command to wait until the modprobe finishes.